# After joining set items into a single string seperated by commas, how to assign that value to a string?

Tags: python, set, combinations

I am using combinations to create certain combination of strings.

```
for subset in combinations(ListOfName, 3):
    print ','.join(subset)
```

this Creates,

```
A,B,C
A,C,D
A,D,E
```

etc.

How can I assign this newly created string to another string so that I can pass this into a function? For example,

```
occuring('A,B,C')
```

Comment: What does *"assign this newly created string to another string"* mean?

Comment: @jonrsharpe added more

Comment: Oh, I see; well why don't you pass the string you're creating to the `occuring` function instead of the `print` statement?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, I did that but its being passed as the set. Like occuring(','.join(subset)) .

Comment: *Sigh.* You really need to get yourself a [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: @jonrsharpe yep, I deserve that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions take arguments by value, so you can simply call the function using the output, for your code it would be something like

```
for subset in combinations(ListOfName, 3):
    arg = ','.join(subset)
    occuring(arg)
```

Comment: Why bother with the assignment?

Comment: Personally I think it's clearer. Not necessary though.

Comment: FWIW I'm also in the habit of binding temporary results this way.  The performance costs are negligible, and since nothing ever works the way I think it should the first time I always wind up having to throw in a `print` anyway.